# Cannot knit RMarkdown with large raster

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, raster, r-raster

I'm running into some issues while knitting an RMarkdown document that reads in a large raster. The code chunk runs without error in the console, but fails when I try and knit the markdown document.

Here is the line in the document that produces the error:

```
r <- raster("./data/very_large_raster.img")

Error in if (x == "" | x == ".") { : argument is of length zero
Calls: <Anonymous> ... raster -> raster -> .local -> .rasterObjectFromFile
Execution halted
```

Comment: Thats an environment issue. When you knit a document, a new R session is used to compile the document. `x` is known in your global environment and therefore the chunk runs without an error. Make youre that `x` is defined inside a code chunk.

Comment: That is mysterious. `x` is known (it is the filename argument provided). Can you add the output of `traceback()` ? Can you try `raster("data/very_large_raster.img")`